# QuerySelector doesnt show what i typed it to do + why doesnt onClick work with a index.html and app.js file?

Tags: javascript, html

First of all why doesnt onClick work when they are on another document? my onclick function is in my js file and onclick on a button on my html file. I tried to make some of my JavaScript in the html file but then the QuerySelector code didnt show the right text when i used console.log(navn);
everything seems fine but doesnt work?

Sorry if its confusing
Im using Sublime 3 in case its important

```js
const navn = document.querySelector('.navn > input');
const password = document.querySelector('.password > input');

function klik() {
  console.log(navn);
  console.log(password);
}
```

```html
<center>
  <p class="navn1">LOG IND</p>
</center>

<div class="navn">
  <span id="navn">Navn: &nbsp;</span> <input type="text" class="inavn"><br><br>
</div>

<center>
  <div class="password">
    <span id="pass">Password: &nbsp;</span> <input type="text"><br>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <button onClick="klik()" class="logind">Log ind</button>
  <br>

  <h1></h1>
<center>
```

Comment: Well, you need to use the `input` element's `.value` property to gets is value

Comment: FYI, the tag `<center>` is long gone and deprecated.

Comment: your `klik` function should be in global scope. Move it outside `.onload` function.

Comment: @LGson What do you mean (the first answer)?

Comment: I mean that `document.querySelector('.navn > input')` will grab the input _element_, not its value. To get its value you need e.g. `document.querySelector('.navn > input').value` .... or using your _const_, `navn.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are created a nested `function` and it will not be called. You need to create a function with global scope  and change it inside `window.onload`

```js
var klik; //declaring a global variable.
window.onload = function(){
  const navn = document.querySelector('.navn > input');
  const password = document.querySelector('.password > input');

   //changing it to the function
  klik = function() {
      console.log(navn);
      console.log(password);
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
            <p class="navn1">LOG IND</p>
        </center>

        <div class="navn">
            <span id="navn">Navn: &nbsp;</span> <input type="text" 
             class="inavn"><br><br>
        </div>

        <center>
            <div class="password">
                <span id="pass">Password: &nbsp;</span> <input 
                type="text"><br>
            </div>

            <br><br>

            <button onClick="klik()" class="logind">Log ind</button>
            <br>

            <h1></h1>
        <center>
```

Comment: @Lasse you can ask anything which seems unclear to you. And accept the answer if its working